# Create custom Android view/widget

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm attempting to create a custom widget which I can use in my activity's layout. I've created a class for the widget which extends `View`.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import be.robinj.ubuntu.R;

public class AppLauncher extends View
{
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private boolean special;
    private AppIcon icon;
    private View view;

    public AppLauncher (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super (context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.widget_applauncher, null, false);

        TypedArray styleAttrs = context.getTheme ().obtainStyledAttributes (attrs, R.styleable.AppLauncher, 0, 0);
        this.name = styleAttrs.getString (R.styleable.AppLauncher_label);
        this.description = styleAttrs.getString (R.styleable.AppLauncher_description);
        this.special = styleAttrs.getBoolean (R.styleable.AppLauncher_special, false);
        this.icon = new AppIcon (styleAttrs.getDrawable (R.styleable.AppLauncher_icon));
    }

    ...
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="64dp"
              android:layout_height="64dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffff9243"
        android:layout_margin="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/launcher_icon_bg">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AppLauncher">
        <attr name="label" format="string" />
        <attr name="description" format="string" />
        <attr name="icon" format="integer" />
        <attr name="special" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

That's all fine, but the Java code is only going to contain the logic part, preferably. <strike>What I can't figure out is how I can specify which layout XML file should be used for my custom view/widget.</strike> *Inflating* the layout presumably loads it. The `inflate ()` methods require a second and third parameter, though. Every example I can find shows `this` being passed as the second parameter, but the second parameter should be a `ViewGroup`, while `this` extends `View`. Where do I magically get this required `ViewGroup` object from? Passing `null` and `false` does not throw an error, but neither does it do anything else (nothing shows up when I run the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pr38y and eldjon for `LayoutInflater`.
In the end the big problem was that I needed to extend `LinearLayout` rather than `View`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to inflate xml in a custom view

```
    public AppLauncher (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
             super (context, attrs);
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             View parent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, this);
    }
```

Comment: `ctrl+shift+o` import your R file.

Comment: I thought *Import Class* would result in importing `android.R` and that somehow my own `R.java` file had faield to compile. I should have checked. Sorry, and thanks :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `this` is not a valid parameter, since `this` is a `View` while a `ViewGroup` is expected. So where am I supposed to get this `ViewGroup` from?

Comment: extend `ViewGroup` class not `View` as you already figured out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your source code that you want to create a `ViewGroup` therefore you need to extend the appropriate class LinearLayout for example. Next you can create an xml file as usual and inflate it in your custom `ViewGroup` constructor:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.ur_view, this);
```

You may then inject your custom view within any layout in the following way:

```
<package.def.AppLauncher .../>
```

or:

```
<View 
      class="package.defAppLauncher"
/View>
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to what the second parameter is, since `this` is not working (because it refers to my `AppLauncher` class). According to the docs it should be a `ViewGroup`, which doesn't really tell me a whole lot.

Comment: When I add the view/widget to my layout it's just empty/invisible, so something's not right.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Passing `null` as a parameter will not add the view to its parent, causing it to not show up.

Comment: if you extend a ViewGroup like LinearLayout that would solve ur problem